# Changing the value of an input in a cloned template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template which I clone. Then I want to change the value of the `input`. It changes the value in the clone object. But the displayed value in the input stays the same. What is the proper way to do it?

```js
let page = document.getElementById("FirstTemplate");
let clone = page.content.cloneNode(true);

clone.children[1].value = "changed";
document.getElementById("page").appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<template id="FirstTemplate">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
</template>

<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: How have you determined the value is staying the same? Are you appending the clone to the DOM? Also, be careful of duplicating `id` attributes as you clone.

Comment: I inspected the clone object in the console and saw that the value property of the input has changed. After that i append it via document.getElementById("page").appendChild(clone); Would you suggest using the data-xxx tags from HTML5 instead? I was already facing this problem, but hadn't the time to find a solution because of this problem.

Comment: In that case I'm unable to replicate as the code you've shown works absolutely fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jb10963h/. Check the console for errors

Comment: I simplified my code a bit for this question but it's the same logic. I will give it a shot. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when you are cloning your template, your `inputs` don't have `value` attribute so you can try like this.

For example add a `value` attribute with payload to the input with `name` id

```
clone.getElementById("name").setAttribute('value','My default value');
```

Hope it helps you.`enter code here`

Comment: The `value` property is always available whether or not its been set previously. Either way, the OPs code already works, so there must be some underlying issues

Comment: It's up to you, I tried and it worked, so if you find cleaner way please share it with me.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean - the OPs code is clean enough and already working...